# Mysql offset and limit is giving ambiguous results when new records are created

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I have a list of say reminders which I am fetching from the `Database` sort by `createdAt` with `limit = 10` and `offsetSent` which is initially 0 and is calculated as, when the fetch happens, the server returns a param `lastOffset = offsetSent + lengthOfRecordsFound`.
Now the problem is when I create a new record, and `refresh` the list by sending an ajax request, it returns me the last same record because, the new record is added to the top and `offset` is still the same.

Does anybody have a solution to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you can swing it, it's better to avoid `OFFSET` and use a pattern like this.

If you're fetching most recent first, set a value first_row to a very large number. Then use it in your query like so.

```
SELECT id, whatever, whatever
  FROM tbl
 WHERE id < ?first_row?
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 10
```

Then, hang on to the last id you fetch. The next time you fetch, use its value for first_row.

In actual practice, you can have each SELECT operation fetch one more row than you need `LIMIT 11`, and just use the last row to get its id value. Then use `WHERE id <= ?first_row?` in place of the offset for the next query.  If the 11th row never turns up in your program, you then know you've fetched everything.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `createdAt` is not unique (why should it?). You need to provide a fully deterministic sort order or any pagination approach you use will fail randomly.

```
-- Latest
ORDER BY createdAt DESC, reminderId DESC

-- Oldest
ORDER BY createdAt, reminderId
```

Answer (score 0):

guys I solved my problem by sending values from the server, `from` and `to` which are basically the `id` of the records I am sending. And I save them in my state of the web app. And query the table for `id < from || id > to`. :)